# Hosting websites directly on VPS vs on Docker containers

Tags: docker, nginx, devops, web-hosting

I want to deploy static and WordPress sites on VPS, and just learned Docker recently.

It seems that I can host multiple websites on server using Nginx to point to specific folders under `/var/www/`, and, on the other hand, I can also create mulitple Docker containers to host different websites. What's the benefit of each of them?

Answer (score 0):

There are differences between the two methods.
Each container has a unique namespace and resource of each container can be limited. If each site is inside a container, specific resources can be allocated to a site and thus the management of server resources is more accurate.
But it is easier to build a WordPress container in which to put a number of sites, so this can not limit the resources that each site uses.